# Should I escape values twice?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, escaping

we are taking input from a web form (which is not under our control) and storing it into a database.

The data is run through PDO (using Zend Db) and stored in a Mysql table on server A, all well and good, the data is escaped as it should be.

We then have a nightly routine which selects the previous days data, exports it as csv, ftps that csv to server B where it is then loaded into another table (which has the same structure as that on server A). I am then using `LOAD DATA IN LOCAL FILE` to pick up the csv file and load it in one go.

My question is this: Am I right in assuming that if the data is properly escaped when loaded into server A, that it will still be safe to just mass load it into server B without explicitly escaping it again?

(server A runs PHP 5.3.7, whereas server B runs 5.2.6)

**EDIT**

To clarify: The `LOAD DATA IN LOCAL FILE` is contained in an sql query invoked via a PHP script, not a straight command line instruction (though it could be if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in assuming that if the data is properly escaped when loaded into server A, that it will still be safe

No.

Like vast majority of PHP folks, you completely misunderstand what "escaping" is and what it is used for.

- "escaping" doesn't make data "safe" at all
- escaping has nothing to do with whatever "protection" or "injection"
- escaping has nothing to do with "user input" or whatever data source.
- escaping has nothing to do with data, as it is for the query, not data.

As a matter of fact, escaping is the only **part** of the formatting rules for only **one** SQL literal. A humble formatting rule, way exaggerated in the minds of PHP users.

What should be your real concern:

- proper **formatting**, not "escaping"
- different SQL literals require different formatting rules. Your "escaping", even if lasted past query execution, would be useless for all query literals beside strings.
- data **destination**, not source
- such a destination is not a database but **SQL query** only. Formatting never goes past query.

TL;DR:
There is no "escaping" past query execution yet "escaping" doesn't make anything safe. And **every** query you run required to be properly formatted.
So, your assumption is wrong.

Also, from the above you may tell that as LOAD DATA IN LOCAL FILE query **doesn't contain any data**, there is no need to format data anyhow, as format is required for SQL query only, as I told you above, not for "data" itself or database.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed response. When you stipulate "proper formatting", do I take it that this would be a task to be done at the Filtering level of FIEO (Filter Input Escape Output).  Take for example a "date of birth" field. If the incoming date was correctly filtered and was always guaranteed to match "nnnn-nn-nn nn:nn:nn" as it was saved on Server A, then actually 'escaping' it would not even be necessary.

Comment: No. that's different formatting. Formatting I am talking about belongs to **SQL language only** and nothing else. It have to be done despite of any other formatting done.

Answer (score 0):

If your importing data through `LOAD DATA IN LOCAL FILE` then the escaping is done for you already. if your inserting through a php extension that doesn't provide underline escaping its best to escape it.